# How to sign an iOS Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode7, code-signing

No matter what I do when trying to build my iOS Framework, I get this error:

"CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 9.3'"

The only "solution" I found through searching was to ensure the framework's project's "Team" is set to None.  That apparently solved the problem for some people, but I still get the same error.

Since that solution was for SDK 8.x I'm wondering if there's something new in SDK 9.x that no longer allows creation of unsigned frameworks?

If I sign it with my developer wildcard credentials, the consuming app is unable to upload to the app store because of a distribution certificate incompatibility.

So is an unsigned ios Framework impossible...?

Comment: New status: Almost there, but not quite.  I was able to sign my framework with "iOS Developer: *" as well as with our Distribution Certificate.  But either way, the consuming app is able to compile.  However, the consuming app gets "ERROR ITMS-90161" when uploading to the AppStore.  I know the framework is signed, however, because I configured the build that way but also because I get "warning: skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed" in the consuming app's Xcode project.  So it appears Xcode is not signing the framework or something like that.  Any ideas what to check next?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't related to framework signing.

Your provisioning profile is wrong.

You must generate provisioning profile exactly.

And you must set up provisioning profile in Xcode Build Setting for code signing.

If your provisioning profile is correct, it will be matched definitely.